# Porto Template:Google map doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf

i'm devolopping a website with **JSF**, and i'm struglling to implment the new **PORTO TEMPLATE**, now i'm at contact us page, it has a map in it which don't show up when i execute and i don't knwo why, and i'm a little weak in JS.
so please help me out !!

***.xhtml:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery.gmap.js"></script>

<script>
    /*
    Map Settings

        Find the Latitude and Longitude of your address:
            - http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm
            - http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude/

     */

    // Map Markers
    var mapMarkers = [ {
        address : "New York, NY 10017",
        html : "<strong>New York Office</strong><br/>New York, NY 10017",
        icon : {
            image : "img/pin.png",
            iconsize : [ 26, 46 ],
            iconanchor : [ 12, 46 ]
        },
        popup : true
    } ];

    // Map Initial Location
    var initLatitude = 40.75198;
    var initLongitude = -73.96978;

    // Map Extended Settings
    var mapSettings = {
        controls : {
            panControl : true,
            zoomControl : true,
            mapTypeControl : true,
            scaleControl : true,
            streetViewControl : true,
            overviewMapControl : true
        },
        scrollwheel : false,
        markers : mapMarkers,
        latitude : initLatitude,
        longitude : initLongitude,
        zoom : 16
    };

    var map = $("#googlemaps").gMap(mapSettings);

    // Map Center At
    var mapCenterAt = function(options, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#googlemaps").gMap("centerAt", options);
    }
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/Publique/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Corporate Software : Nous Contactez </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div role="main" class="main">

            <section class="page-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="index">Acceuil</a></li>
                            <li class="active">Nous Contactez</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Nous Contactez</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>

            <!-- Google Maps -->
            <div id="googlemaps" class="google-map hidden-xs"></div>

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contactSuccess">
                            <strong>Succés!</strong> Nous avons reçus votre message.
                        </div>

                        <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contactError">
                            <strong>Erreure!</strong> Une Erreure c'est produite lors du
                            l'envois de votre message.
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="short">
                            Nous <strong>Contactez</strong>
                        </h2>

                        <h:form id="form1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Nom Complet *</label>
                                        <h:inputText type="text"
                                            value="#{messageMBean.message.nomComplet}"
                                            data-msg-required="Entrer votre nom s'il vous plait."
                                            maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Votre email *</label>
                                        <h:inputText type="email"
                                            value="#{messageMBean.message.email}"
                                            data-msg-required="Entrer votre email s'il vous plait."
                                            data-msg-email="Entrer un email valide s'il vous plait."
                                            maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label>Sujet *</label>
                                        <h:inputText type="text"
                                            value="#{messageMBean.message.objet}"
                                            data-msg-required="Please enter the subject."
                                            maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="subject"
                                            id="subject" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label>Message *</label>
                                        <h:inputTextarea maxlength="5000"
                                            value="#{messageMBean.message.textMessage}"
                                            data-msg-required="Entrer votre message s'il vous plait."
                                            rows="10" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h:commandButton value="Envoyer"
                                        actionListener="#{messageMBean.save}"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                                        <p:ajax update="form1" />
                                    </h:commandButton>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </h:form>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <h4 class="push-top">
                            Get in <strong>touch</strong>
                        </h4>
                        <p>
                            Si vous êtes interéssés par nos services, ou bien vous voulez
                            faire partie de notre equipe, ou vous avez n'import quelle
                            Question!! <strong>N'hesitez pas !</strong>
                        </p>

                        <hr />

                        <h4>
                            Notre <strong>Agence</strong>
                        </h4>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i> <strong>Addresse:</strong>
                                6 bis, rue Najib Mahfoud, Casablanca</li>
                            <li><i class="icon icon-phone"></i> <strong>TéléPhone:</strong>
                                0212 522 266 545/90</li>
                            <li><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> <strong>Email:</strong>
                                <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">Corporate@corporate.ma</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <hr />

                        <h4>
                            <strong>Heurs</strong> de Travail
                        </h4>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><i class="icon icon-time"></i> Lundi - Vendredi 9am to
                                5pm</li>
                            <li><i class="icon icon-time"></i> Samedi - 9am to 2pm</li>
                            <li><i class="icon icon-time"></i> Dimanche - Fermé</li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <section class="call-to-action featured footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="center">
                    <h3>
                        Corporate Software, c'est <strong>tous</strong> ce dont vous avez
                        <strong>besoin</strong>! <a
                            href="http://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/4106987"
                            target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
                            data-appear-animation="bounceIn">Contactez Nous!</a> <span
                            class="arrow hlb" data-appear-animation="rotateInUpLeft"
                            style="top: -22px;"></span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

-----------EDITED-----------

I think i understand what happened but don't know how to undo it !!!

when xhtml is parsed to html any thing between `<script>` tags becomes in between comments `<!-- -->` i looked it up, it seems some kind of hacking countermeasure!!!, but i don't know how to disable it.

any ideas !!. 
think you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution it's very easy,and i taught that ishould share it in case anyone needs it.

You create new javascript file in your project and copy the JS code in it instand of writing in the xhtml file.

Then include it in the xhtml with `<script src="file.js"></script>` in the head section and voila !!!

it's working!!!!